# C++ vector<vector<int>>`select only entries that appear just once

Tags: c++, vector

I have `vector<vector<int>>` which has following entries:

2 3
3 4
2 3
4 5
5 6

I need to create another `vector<vector<int>>` with entries that apeears just once.
So:

3 4
4 5
5 6

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Is it always pairs of integers? If so, I'd recommend using `std::pair`

Comment: What do you mean by entry, element or row?

Comment: Create a type that represents a pair, whose comparison operator work according to your rules (or use `std::pair`) then build a `std::set` from the vector to remove duplicates.

Comment: The C++ standard library has many [nice algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), including one called [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Comment: I tried the following code. I don't need to remove duplicates, I need to remove duplicates + its originals, like 1 1 2 2 3 4 5 and I need to have 3 4 5
`for(unsigned int i=1;i<TTT.size()-1;++i)

{

vector<int>& r1 = TTT[i-1];

vector<int>& r2 = TTT[i];

if ((TTT[i-1][0] == TTT[i][0]) && (TTT[i-1][1] == TTT[i][1])) 

{TTT.erase (TTT.begin()+i-1,TTT.begin()+i+1);
i = i - 1;}}`

Comment: Edit your question to contain that code - you've got better formatting options there, and it will be a lot more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This gives the result your looking for.** Using a `std::map` and `std::pair`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> count_map;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > v;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > v2;
    int a[10] = {2,3,3,4,2,3,4,5,5,6};

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int first = a[i];
        int second = a[++i];
        std::pair<int, int> p = std::make_pair(first, second);
        v.push_back(p);
        count_map[p]++;
    }

    for(auto it = count_map.begin(); it != count_map.end(); ++it) {
        if(it->second != 1) continue;
        v2.push_back(it->first);
        std::cout << it->first.first << ", " << it->first.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have included two code examples.
The function "add_pair" adds the pair of integers if it's not yet been added.
THe function "make_pairs_with_two_vectors" gives you both the unsorted and sorted vector.
The function "make_pairs_with_one_vector" gives you only the sorted vector.

```
void add_pair(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& _MyPairs, std::pair<int, int> _Pair) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _MyPairs.size(); i++) {
        if (_MyPairs[i].first == _Pair.first && _MyPairs[i].second == _Pair.second) {
            return;
        }
    }
    _MyPairs.push_back(_Pair);
}

void make_pairs_with_two_vectors() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> my_pairs;
    my_pairs.push_back(std::pair<int, int>(2, 3));
    my_pairs.push_back(std::pair<int, int>(3, 4));
    my_pairs.push_back(std::pair<int, int>(2, 3));
    my_pairs.push_back(std::pair<int, int>(4, 5));
    my_pairs.push_back(std::pair<int, int>(5, 6));

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> my_pairs_once;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < my_pairs.size(); i++) {
        add_pair(my_pairs_once, my_pairs[i]);
    }
}

void make_pairs_with_one_vector() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> my_pairs;
    add_pair(my_pairs, std::pair<int, int>(2, 3));
    add_pair(my_pairs, std::pair<int, int>(3, 4));
    add_pair(my_pairs, std::pair<int, int>(2, 3));
    add_pair(my_pairs, std::pair<int, int>(4, 5));
    add_pair(my_pairs, std::pair<int, int>(5, 6));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate the data with `std::pair`, you can use `std::sort` and `std::unique` :

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> vPairs;
std::sort(vPairs.begin(), vPairs.end());
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>::iterator it;
it = std::unique(vPairs.begin(), vPairs.end()); // iterator keeps the last unique element position
vPairs.resize( std::distance(vPairs.begin(),it) ); // resize according to unique pair number
```

Comment: You can do the same on vector of vectors, too. But this will not work because one of duplicates will stay.

Comment: You should probably `erase` the end of the vector after calling `std::unique`: `vPairs.erase(std::unique(vPairs.begin(), vPairs.end()), vPairs.end())`

Comment: If I have 3 elements in one entry, what can I use insted of "pairs"?

Comment: If I have <1, 2, 3> <1, 2, 4>, <2, 2, 5> and I need to check first 2 elements (1, 2) in one entry to remove both entries that have it <1, 2, 3> and <1, 2, 4> and have finally <2, 2, 5>